# Python - binning

Tags: python, binning

I'm generating a series of values and would like to bin them.  I'd rather not use numpy or the like. Is there something more pythonic than:

```
bins = [20,30,40]
results = [0,0,0,0]

for _ in range(iterations):
    x = somefunction()
    for n, bin in enumerate(bins):
        if x < bin:
            results[n] += 1
            break
    else:
        results[-1] += 1

final = [100 * r / float(iterations) for r in results]
print(final)
```

Comment: You might get better answers at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KevinReid answers so far seem reasonable, but it may be worth trying. I tend to think of codereview for something more complex that this question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like that:

```
r = [0] * (len(bins) + 1)
for _ in xrange(iterations):
    r[next((i for i, bin in enumerate(bins) if somefunction() < bin), -1)] += 1
```

or alternatively a counter:

```
n = len(bins)
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
c.update(
    next((i for i, bin in enumerate(bins) if somefunction() < bin), n)
    for _ in xrange(iterations)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better/faster (for larger arrays) to use a binary search algorithm instead of a linear search algorithm.

That is,

```
def binm(rr,ra):
  ih=len(ra)-1
  il=0
  if rr<ra[il]: return il
  while (ih-il>1):
    ie=(ih+il)/2
    if rr<ra[ie]:
      ih=ie
    else:
      il=ie
  return ih

bins = [20,30,40]
results = [0,0,0,0]

for _ in range(iterations):
  x = somefunction()
  ib=binm(x,bins)
  results[ib]+=1
```

Comment: As you say, good idea for larger arrays, but probably overkill for this situation.